# Seacrh key and get val for that in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am working on mongo and need to implement a search page where i want the values from a document.
i have created a sample on mongoplayground.com [Click Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b1dK-WwaG1r)

The result should be for example when search string is "a" then get val of all keys starts from "a" letter.

data and code sample is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b1dK-WwaG1r)

Comment: I would suggest you to improve you schema design, see how to [improve your schema](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/performance-advisor/schema-suggestions/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i will take care of that, but this data is from words api and i have to use this in that way only.

Comment: You can use regex matching in `$match` like this `{
    $match: {
      "word.k": {
        $regex: "^a.*",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }`. However you will have nested objects as values.

Comment: Further to what @turivishal wrote, I think you will find that using any data as field names will only lead to future querying pain.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will try this once or last option is to change the schema a little bit